# Assert on a standard controller

Tags: apex, unit-test, standardcontroller, extension

I am starting to learn writing testclasses but dont know

> how to assert on a standard controller

see my code below

```
public class accSearchController {

    public string searchStringContact {get;set;}
    public string searchStringPhone {get;set;}
    public list<account> accList{set;get;}
    public List<Contact> contactList{get;set;}
    private string searchString='';
    private string searchVar='';

    private ApexPages.StandardController std;
    public accSearchController(ApexPages.StandardController stdCtrl) {
        std=stdCtrl;
    }

    public void search(){
        IF(searchStringContact!=''){
            searchString= searchStringContact;
            searchVar='lastname';
        }ELSE{searchString= searchStringPhone;
            searchVar='Phone';
        }  

        string searchquery='SELECT id,Name,(SELECT id,lastname,firstname,Phone,LeadSource,DoNotCall FROM Contacts )FROM Account WHERE id IN (Select AccountId from contact WHERE '+searchVar+' LIKE \'%'+searchString+'%\') Limit 5';
        accList= Database.query(searchquery); 
        system.debug('accList '+accList);       
    }
}
```

// test class

```
@isTest
private class accSearchControllerTestClass {

    @isTest  
    private static void testsearch() 
    { 
        account testccount;
        string searchStringContact='';
        //Create searchstring
        ApexPages.StandardController sc = new                 
        ApexPages.standardController(testccount);
        //ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('id', 'test');
        accSearchController myPageCon = new accSearchController(sc);

        System.assertEquals(myPageCon,null);   
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the problem you facing? And what help you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Apex_testing](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/apex/apex_testing.htm)

[Writing Efficient Test Classes](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000fy8lIAA)

```
@isTest
public class accSearchControllerTestClass {
    @isTest  
    private static void testsearch() 
    { 
        List<account> accounts=new list<account>();
        accounts.add(new account(Name='account1'));
        accounts.add(new account(Name='account2'));
        accounts.add(new account(Name='account3'));
        insert accounts;

        list<contact> contacts=new list<contact>();                
        contacts.add(new contact(AccountId=accounts[0].id,lastname='contact1LastName',firstname='Contact1FirstName',Phone=9876543210,LeadSource='web',DoNotCall__c=''));
        contacts.add(new contact(AccountId=accounts[0].id,lastname='contact2LastName',firstname='Contact2FirstName',Phone=9876543211,LeadSource='web',DoNotCall__c=''));
        contacts.add(new contact(AccountId=accounts[1].id,lastname='contact3LastName',firstname='Contact3FirstName',Phone=9876543211,LeadSource='web',DoNotCall__c=''));
        Insert Contacts;


        ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.standardController(accounts[2]);
        accSearchController myPageCon = new accSearchController(sc);
        myPageCon.searchStringContact='contact1LastName';        
        myPageCon.search();
        System..assertNotEquals(myPageCon.accList.size(),1);  
        myPageCon.searchStringContact=''; 
        myPageCon.searchStringPhone ='9876543211';
        myPageCon.search();
        System..assertNotEquals(myPageCon.accList.size(),2);  
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The focus of your test should be the behaviour of the code you have written. Most of what you need to know is described in [Testing Custom Controllers and Controller Extensions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_error_handling.htm).

For your current case:

```
// Your test method needs to insert the data that it is going to search for
Account account = new Account(Name = 'Acme');
insert account;
Contact contact = new Contact(
        FirstName = 'Jane',
        LastName = 'Doe',
        AccountId = account.Id
        );
insert contact;

accSearchController c = new accSearchController(sc);
c.searchStringContact = 'Doe';
c.search();
System.assertEquals(1, c.accList.size();
// Add more asserts on c.accList
```

Also to avoid the risk of [SOQL Injection](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_security_tips_soql_injection.htm) use [escapeSingleQuotes](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm) in your controller extension.